# bin/rails:5: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I run "rails s" show me this message "bin/rails:5: syntax error, unexpected tCONSTANT, expecting end-of-input" Can anyone help me?

Comment: Did you mess with the bin/rails file?

Comment: Can you show the full error log?

Comment: You might be missing a quotation mark to define the end of a string. `"` or `'`